# VBA QueryTables Connection Error with HTML Tables

Tags: html, vba, connection

I am trying to extract the exchange rates from an IMF tsv file and my code keeps trying to contact the server for information. In the past it did work. If I terminate the code by pressing esc, it does provide the new data.

What am I doing wrong? Does anyone have a suggestion to prevent this from happening?

```
 Sub IMF()
    Dim ConnString As String
    Dim wsIMF As Worksheet
    Set wsIMF = Sheets("IMF Exchange rates")
    
    wsIMF.Cells.ClearContents
    ConnString = "TEXT;http://www.imf.org/external/np/fin/data/rms_five.aspx?tsvflag=Y"
        With wsIMF.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=ConnString, Destination:=wsIMF.Range("A1"))
            .Name = _
            " "
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = False
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 775
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
            .TextFileDecimalSeparator = ","
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Try to use XML to do web scraping, use query is unreliabel

Comment: Did you want all tables or a specific one?

Comment: @kin-siang Thanks for your suggestion, will try to do so.

Comment: @QHarr I'd like to receive the data from both tables.